# NSDictionary memory issue

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I was created one small business application..Here I got the data from server and Parsed it and then display the data... Here The datas are stored in NSDictionary....For the use of NSDictionary i took Large amount of memory..Any replacement for NSDictionary and it will takes less memory.....

Comment: The question is a bit inaccurate. What type of data is stored in the dictionary, what kind of the replacement are you looking for? If you need to download some pretty big binary data from the server - store it as a binary file and download via the NSURLDownload.

Comment: What kind of data are u parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data framework or sqlite3, the former one is Apple's native object graph management framework which provides kinda object-relational mapping features but is not actually an ORM(, though wikipedia does include Core Data in its ORM list).

Comment: Core Data **is not an ORM** it provides a object graph.